# i m unable to use anchor tag in my single page application

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm learning single page application using angularJS using the ui-router module. But on my main HTML page, the anchor tag is not working, I'm stuck now, please can anyone help?

---

```
<a ui-sref="page_one"><b>Page_One</b></a>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
<a ui-sref="page_two"><b>Page_Two</b></a>

<br><br>
<div ui-view></div>

<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/page_one.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/page_two.js"></script>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Describe your problem and your question. You don't say a lot here.

Comment: while running this HTML page i m not getting the content in the anchor tag as link its just showing as simple text.......

Comment: easy fix is to add `href=""` to them to make the browser realize they are links.

Answer (score 0):

If an anchor element doesn't contain an `href` attribute, some browsers will not style it as a link.

In your case, a good solution would be to target the particular `ui-sref` attribute to use the styles you want.

```
<style>
/* specifically targeting anchor links with the ui-sref attribute */
a[ui-sref*='page'] {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor:pointer;
}
</style>

<a ui-sref="page_two"><b>Page_Two</b></a>
```

Notice I'm using a wildcard CSS selector to apply the styles, because in your example the two attribute values started with 'page'. However, you can use something more granular, or less granular, depending on your needs. Obviously, you can also add the styles you wish.